# Android Why can I update ui in a non-ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Here is my simple code and logcat

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        println("onCreate " + Thread.currentThread().name)

        Thread(){

            println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().name)
            textView.text = "1"
        }.start()

        textView.setOnClickListener {

            Thread(){

                println("Thread click " + Thread.currentThread().name)
                textView.text = "1"
            }.start()
        }
    }
```

```
onCreate main
Thread Thread-2
```

I am confused why I can update ui on `Thread-2`

Then I click the textView and get log

```
onCreate main
Thread Thread-2
Thread click Thread-3
```

the app crashed and get error`Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

It's ok because i can't update ui on Thread-3.

But why Thread-2 can?

Comment: you can execute other jobs, but if in that thread you change UI then you should add `runOnUIThread`

Comment: @DươngMinh i know `runOnUIThread` works. But why Thread-2 don't need `runOnUIThread`?

Comment: Because you got lucky.  You really don't need to know how / why you got lucky.  All you really need to know is ... Don't Do It.

Answer (score 0):

Updating UI on main thread only is not strictly enforced everywhere and sometimes the view system is in a state where you can get away with it. You should not be doing so anyway.

You can examine the stacktrace of `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` to learn where the main thread enforcement is in your case.

Answer (score -1):

UI can only be updated in the Main Thread

```
runOnUiThread {
    //code that runs in main
}
```